# angularjs filter not compiling correctly with coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I used try coffeescript and it compiles correctly but in my app I installed the filter using yo:angular filter capitialize and it created the file correctly but when I serve the app I get a typeerr because it is missing a ')' before .filter.

```
'use strict'

angular.module 'someapp'
  .filter 'capitialize', ->
    (input) ->
      'capitialize filter: ' + input
```

compiles to:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('someapp'.filter('capitialize', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return 'capitialize filter: ' + input;
    };
  }));

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be something with the yeoman app I am using, running yo angular:filter name then manually adding ( ) around the module seems to fix the issue.

```
'use strict'

angular.module('someapp')
  .filter 'capitialize', ->
    (input) ->
      'capitialize filter: ' + input
```